# Map a key to switch between my favorite weapons for each class?

Tags: team-fortress-2

Is there some way to map a key so that it switches between my favorite weapons for each class?

I haven't played much Team Fortress 2 yet, but for most of the classes I use one or two weapons. I often use "q" to easily switch between these weapons, but by default "q" switches between the weapons mapped to the keys 1 and 2. Is it possible to configure a button so that it will always switch between my favorite weapons? For example, it could switch between flamethrower and axe for Pyro and pistol and cloaking for Spy.

Update: My motivation is that I, when I die, have to remember to switch between my favorite weapons. If I don't I find myself in a situation where I switch to the wrong weapon causing me to die way to many times...

Comment: I've ingrained myself into a habit when I spawn as spy to automatically swap to the knife then the sapper then press Q a couple of times... I do it every single time :/

Comment: Exactly! That's what I'm trying to avoid! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check an option under multiplayer -> advanced to "remember last weapon between lives". That should make it easier to keep "Q" rotating between your preferred weapons -- You'll only have to swap between them once, when you first spawn as that class.

Answer (score 4):

By default <kbd>Q</kbd> should switch between your last used weapons. So if you first use your flame-thrower and then your axe <kbd>Q</kbd> should first switch back to the flame-thrower and then back to the axe again.

Comment: I'll also add: you can check an option under multiplayer -> advanced to "remember last weapon between lives" which means you don't have to reset your last weapon each time you die if, say, you like 1 and 3 (otherwise would revert back to 1 and 2 each time).

Comment: Raven Dreamer: Good point! I edited the description of the question because I realized the problem is that I forget to switch weapons every time I die. Would you like to post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't have enough reputation to comment yet, I'll just add to the post about the Q hotkey.

I usually map "switch between last used weapons" to fourth mouse button ( the one at my thumb ). This really speeds things up, and frees up your strafe-fingers for WASD for an extra millisecond or two ;)

Comment: That's a very useful tip!